# UI5: Adding a new initial selection criteria view to worklist app

Tags: controller, selection, sapui5

I downloaded UI5 worklist template and was trying to add a new view to accept user input for initial selection criteria. I was able to do it correctly to the point setting new view "Selection" as initial view to start with by adjusting router setting in manifest.json and also added code to pass the user entered criteria as a filter object to worklist table thought "Update started" event of table in onInit() of worklist.controller as shown in below picture.

Issue:- Filters are getting applied only for the first time when user navigating from "selection" view to "worklist". After that if user wants to go back to selection view and modify the selection criteria and perform the search again, worklist is view is getting displayed with old data only and seems to effect of new criteria.

[image: worklist.controller.js]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main (good) ways of doing this, both involving routing.

Firstly (easier solution), you can simply move your code inside a event handler for the `patternMatched` event of your worklist route. Alternatively, you could also listen to the [display](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.routing.Targets.html#event:display) event of the router's targets, but I highly recommend you to use the `patternMatched` route event instead.

Basically, this event will be triggered each time the route is matched (i.e. each time the view is displayed). You can do it with something along the lines of:

```js
onInit: function() {
    // ... your current code
    var oRouter = this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter();
    oRouter.getRoute("worklist").attachPatternMatched(this.onRouteMatched, this);
},

// ...

onRouteMatched: function() {
    var oTable = this.byId("myTable"), //replace the ID accordingly :)
        aFilters = ...;
    oTable.getBinding("items").filter(aFilters);
}
```

The second option is basically an extension of the first one. It might not be suitable for your use case (it depends on the filters that the user may select on the first screen). You still need to make the same methods. But instead of directly retrieving the selection of the first screen, you would be passing the data through the routing mechanism.

This has the nice caveat that if the user refreshes the window, he will still get the filtered view (as opposed with the first solution, when you would always get an unfiltered one after refresh). The same basic principle from the [UI5 Routing Walkthrough](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/e85da535ea19430a90c381f3c2bd748e.html) could be used and extended (i.e. you will have to represent your filters as a string; basically 'serializing' them into the string in your "Selection" view, passing the string to the router in the `navTo` call, and then 'deserializing' the string on in the worklist view). Make sure to look at the next step from the walthrough as well.

Of course, if the user can select an unlimited or large number of filters, this solution won't work out.

Comment: I like the option 1. It is working as I needed. Thank you @Serban. all the time I was searching several option with in the view events. never got a thought of router events.